# Advertising Platform

Tags: system, point, ads

I'm 100% sure that this isn't the right form to post a question like this, but I hope someone on here has the answer to my question.

Is there advertising platform that sends a true or false response dependent on if the user finishes the ad video to the server so I can add points to the users account.

(I don't need help adding points, or creating a point system, just an advertising platform that would be easy to integrate with the videos on my site)

I understand if this isn't the right forum for this, if someone could point me in the right direction. Before you say anything, yes I have googled, just can't find anything that suits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need a video player that supports the [VAST](https://www.iab.com/guidelines/digital-video-ad-serving-template-vast-3-0/) protocol

> VAST provides a common protocol that enables ad servers to use a
>   single ad response format across multiple publishers/video players

This format allows to specify the so-called **tracking elements** - URIs that would be called once a particular events occurs. You can manually provide a VAST xml response with a tracking element for a video completion event.

Also consider using [DFP](https://www.google.com/dfp) to serve your video ads - it's free up until a certain traffic volume and would track everything you might need